# Calculating Hours/Mins Ago based on DB Field and CurrentTime

Tags: php, time

**Code Giving me Trouble:**

```
    foreach($result as $row)
    { 

    echo "<div class='listing'>";
        print $row['uUName'] . '</strong><br />' .
        '<strong>' . $row['listTitle'] . '</strong><br />' .
        $arr = explode(':', $row['LISTDIFF']);
        echo "$arr[0] minutes, $arr[1] seconds";
    echo "</div>";
    }
```

This outputs: `Array minutes, seconds` . Why is the array empty?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do the date calculations [in MySQL](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_timediff):

```
SELECT TIMEDIFF(listDT, now())
```

which returns the difference as a string in the format `hh:mm:ss.ssss`, which you can then massage in PHP to add the 'minutes' and 'seconds' text.

---

```
$arr = explode(':', $result['LISTDIFF']);
echo "$arr[0] minutes, $arr[1] seconds";
```

Comment: how do I call this in my php script though?

Comment: Is it still just: $row['listDt'] ?

Comment: You're doing a DB query, so add it to the original query that gives you that `$sth1` result. Then the post-processing is just simple simple string operations and maybe an `explode(':',...)`

Comment: Please show an example, I am not following you. How do I output the value of `TIMEDIFF(listDT, now())`

Comment: I added it in the the query and the $row[''], but its showing the times as: -01:44:18

Comment: `SELECT TIMEDIFF(listDT, now()) AS diff` -> $row['diff']`

Comment: `-03:35:53`, `-01:44:18` , how do I transform these to `1 hour 44 minutes ago` for example

Comment: flip the arguments, so it's `now(), listDT)`, then like I said earlier, use [explode()](http://php.net/explode)

Comment: `explode(":", $row['LISTDIFF']) ` seems to just output array. I tried looking at the php.net site, there weren't too helpful examples for this one there. Would you mind helping?

Comment: `$arr = explode(':', $diff); $string = "$arr[0] minutes, $arr[1] seconds"`. you can always use `var_dump` and `print_r`) to spit out an array to see how it's structured.

Comment: Marc, thanks for that. I tried implementing and am getting an output of `array`, please see above additions

Comment: see edit in answer... if I may suggest, take some time and learn PHP a bit better. This last bit is just simple string manipulation stuff, and if you can't figure that out on your own, you should study things a bit more before attempting them.

Comment: It appears my array is empty?

Comment: When I do a print_r($arr), it just gives me "Array"